# What is the proper way to setup Rados Gateway (RGW) under Ceph using Cephadm?

Tags: 22.04, ceph

I have setup a 'reef' Ceph Cluster using Cephadm and Ansible in a lab environment. I have buckets and pools already setup. The ceph.io site is confusing on how to setup the Rados Gateway (radosgw) with Multi-site -- https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/radosgw/multisite/

I am running this on Ubuntu 22.04 VMs under VMware ESXi 7 and using the documentation per Canonical's Ceph's Multi-Site - https://ubuntu.com/ceph/docs/multi-site.

NOTE: We are, however, not using Juju since it has a nasty learning curve and want to install Ceph natively.

Is a copy of HAProxy also needed for handling the front-end load balancing or is it implied that Ceph sets it up?

Command-line scripting I was planning on using for setting up the RGW:

```
radosgw-admin realm create --rgw-realm=sandbox --default
radosgw-admin zonegroup create --rgw-zonegroup=sandbox  --master --default
radosgw-admin zone create --rgw-zonegroup=sandbox --rgw-zone=sandbox --master --default
radosgw-admin period update --rgw-realm=sandbox --commit
ceph orch apply rgw sandbox --realm=sandbox --zone=sandbox --placement="2 ceph-mon1 ceph-mon2" --port=8000
```

What other steps are needed to get the RGW up and running so that it can be presented to something like Veeam for doing performance and I/O testing concepts?

Comment: please [edit] your question indicating how it relates to ubuntu